# iAd not displaying on app

Tags: ios, iad

I have an iOS app that uses the iAD network. A user who has downloaded the app in France can see an iAd banner fine, but I cannot see any iAd banners myself. I am from the UK.

In my account, I have the following stats over the past 14 days:

- 51,668 requests
- 56 impressions
- 0.11% fill rate
- 0.12% iAd fill rate
- 0.00% TTR

I have also not made any revenue for a good while.

The part about this I don't understand is that I used to make revenue from the iAd network and also see the banners myself around Summer last year.

I haven't changed any details and my contract is fine, so I don't know what has happened.

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas as to why this is happening and how I could fix it?

Thanks